# Issue with counting number of items in an array - Count not showing up

Tags: php, multi-select

I'm trying to capture user choices from a multi-select form into PHP so I can match the user choices with what is required. The following is the HTML:

```
<tr>
<!-- <label for="DutiesDesc">Duties Description:&nbsp;</label><textarea name="DutiesDesc" cols="30" rows="5" /></textarea>-->
<td><label for="DutiesDesc">Job Attributes:</label></td>
<td><select name="DutiesDesc[]" size="<?php $items ?>" multiple="multiple">

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($attribid)) 
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['AttribName']?>"><?php echo $row['AttribName']?></option>

<?php }?>
   </select></td>
</tr>
```

The options display correctly, the following part is where I take the user input and store it in an array for later use. Also please note that the displayed multi-select box option are retrieved from a MySQL database.

```
//Array to store user input from the multiselect box

$SkillsArray = $_POST['DutiesDesc'];
//Count the number of items in the array
$counter = count($SkillsArray);
```

Just for testing purposes,  I count the number of items in the Array and display them as:

```
echo $counter;
```

But I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: on $counter.

I think this may mean that the `$skillsarray` doesn't have any values or user selected options didn't save into the variables. Please assist.

Comment: i made a small test file, based on your code... it works...

http://bugunkandilmi.com/php_test/test.php here you can see.

Comment: Your solution should work, can you send whole code how you are using the count and where you write out the count?
This should be ok:
$counter = count($SkillsArray);
echo $counter;
I think that you are calling echo $count before the count() function or in another context.

Comment: FYI, even if the user didn't select any options, you should have got 0 as output.

Comment: I'l have another look at the sequence of my code